# What exactly is watchdog?

Tags: log-messages

I am aware of the watchdog table in the Drupal database, but I am not sure how to use it effectively.  Is it simply a message function that adds to the table like a stack in the database for debugging?  I have found old references to modules and odds and ends in content, but have not located a broad discussion of different ways it can be used effectively.  Also, how do I get the reports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/6 talks about the `watchdog()` call, and you access the reports it generates from `admin/reports/dblog` provided that you've turned on the optional Database Logging core module (dblog).